# SQL statement to test foreign key field with variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

**Products**

- id
- producttype
- ...
- ...

**Productsapplied**

- id
- productid
- ...
- ...

How would I got about doing this, Basically at each point I need to test the relevant product with the query `$type`.

I am not sure on how I can use the `productid` on each row to check if that particular product type is the same as the one queried `$type`.

`SELECT * FROM productsapplied where 'productapplied'.productid->producttype = $type`

Any help or tips in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT ProductsApplied.* FROM products INNER JOIN Products ON ProductsApplied.ProductID = Products.ID WHERE Products.ProductType = 'whatever'`? If not, please add sample table rows and expected results to your question.

Comment: hi, i just edited the question after re reading and sounding to vague. I think that could be what I mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT * 
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN productapplied AS pa ON pa.productid = p.id
WHERE p.producttype = $TYPE
```